# Error in object creation (backend controller)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord

I'm going crazy over this, cause I've tried eveything possible. Here's the deal: I'm creating a discord bot that logs and stores 2 user activities (when he joins and when he leaves a voice channel).

I'm using MongoDB and Mongoose ODM. Here is the `ActivitySchema` model:

```
const mongoose = require("../database")

const ActivitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        id: String,
        name: String
    },
    from: {
        id: String,
        name: String
    },
    to: {
        id: String,
        name: String
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
})

const Activity = mongoose.model("Activity", ActivitySchema)

module.exports = Activity
```

Here are the first 5 document rows (I've changed user names for privacy reasons):

```
[
   {
      "user":{
         "id":"258626789922832385",
         "name":"User 1"
      },
      "from":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null
      },
      "to":{
         "id":"712011063867998349",
         "name":"OH GUI OH BOIII II"
      },
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z",
      "_id":"600da5e744dfcb399410fe53",
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "id":"338750711393157121",
         "name":"User 2"
      },
      "from":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null
      },
      "to":{
         "id":"712011063867998349",
         "name":"OH GUI OH BOIII II"
      },
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z",
      "_id":"600da5ea44dfcb399410fe54",
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "id":"258626789922832385",
         "name":"User 1"
      },
      "from":{
         "id":"712011063867998349",
         "name":"OH GUI OH BOIII II"
      },
      "to":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null
      },
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z",
      "_id":"600da70244dfcb399410fe56",
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "id":"258626789922832385",
         "name":"User 1"
      },
      "from":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null
      },
      "to":{
         "id":"712011063867998349",
         "name":"OH GUI OH BOIII II"
      },
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z",
      "_id":"600da70844dfcb399410fe57",
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "id":"162677448897462272",
         "name":"User 3"
      },
      "from":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null
      },
      "to":{
         "id":"712011063867998349",
         "name":"OH GUI OH BOIII II"
      },
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T17:13:40.309Z",
      "_id":"600daafccb560a2e841b25c2",
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

Then I created a function that is supposed to return an array of objects with the following properties: `id, users (users connected), user (who joined or left), type (join or leave) and timestamp`.

```
const Activity = require("../models/activity.model")

async function getUsage(req, res) {
    try {
        const activities = await Activity.find()

        let state = []
        let users = []
        let id = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
            id++
            const activity = activities[i]
            if (activity.from.id !== null && activity.to.id !== null) continue

            const type = activity.from.id === null || activity.to.id !== null ? "join" : "leave"

            if (type === "join" && !users.find(user => user.id === activity.user.id)) {
                users.push({ id: activity.user.id, name: activity.user.name })
            }

            if (type === "leave") {
                users = users.filter(user => user.id !== activity.user.id)
            }

            state.push({
                id,
                users,
                user: activity.user,
                type,
                timestamp: activity.timestamp
            })
        }

        return res.send(state)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send({ error: "Error" })
    }
}

module.exports = { getUsage }
```

And there is an issue right in the first element:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "users":[
         {
            "id":"258626789922832385",
            "name":"User 1"
         },
         {
            "id":"338750711393157121",
            "name":"User 2"
         }
      ],
      "user":{
         "id":"258626789922832385",
         "name":"User 1"
      },
      "type":"join",
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "users":[
         {
            "id":"258626789922832385",
            "name":"User 1"
         },
         {
            "id":"338750711393157121",
            "name":"User 2"
         }
      ],
      "user":{
         "id":"338750711393157121",
         "name":"User 2"
      },
      "type":"join",
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z"
   }
]
```

According to my data, it should be:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "users":[
         {
            "id":"258626789922832385",
            "name":"User 1"
         }
      ],
      "user":{
         "id":"258626789922832385",
         "name":"User 1"
      },
      "type":"join",
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "users":[
         {
            "id":"258626789922832385",
            "name":"User 1"
         },
         {
            "id":"338750711393157121",
            "name":"User 2"
         }
      ],
      "user":{
         "id":"338750711393157121",
         "name":"User 2"
      },
      "type":"join",
      "timestamp":"2021-01-24T16:52:02.999Z"
   }
]
```

And it keeps getting weirder in the following elements!.

Please help :)

Comment: what do you want exactly? explain more users (users connected), user (who joined or left), type (join or leave)

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I want to iterate over the Activities array and map an object that returns an array of connected users at that iteration. E.g.: Imagine a for loop that starts with i = 0, goes to the length of the array and adds 1 to i - when i = 0, the users array should be ["User 1"], when i = 1 it should be ["User 1", "User 2"], but it isn't doing that.